# Resources display differently between using view based system and Compose based

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

1. I use the following method on the traditional layout

   ```
   fun getRealDimenByActivity(context: Context, id:Int) : Float{
       return context.resources.getDimension(id)/getDensity(context as Activity)
   }

   fun getDensity(activity : Activity) : Float{
       val dm = DisplayMetrics()
       activity.windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(dm)
       return dm.density
   }
   ```
2. I use the following method on compose

   ```
   fun mySp(id : Int) : TextUnit{

       return getRealDimenByActivityByContext(WearApp.getApplicationContext(),id).sp
   }
   ```

==============

The values I obtained above are the same.

But it's different

Comment: last,it' different show

Comment: Post an actual image so that we know what the differences look like.